# Determing which term of the geometric sequence a number is equal to

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, geometric-series

The question is: Which term of the geometric sequece $4,12,36,\ldots$ is equal to $78732.$

My process of working it out is:

$t_n= t_1\cdot r^{n-1}$

$78372 = 4\cdot3^{n-1}$

$78372 = 12^{n-1}$

From here onwards I am not sure on what to do. Like how do I go further into solving which term it is. Any steps or comments if I am on the right track or any help is appreciated

Comment: $$4\cdot3^{n-1}\ne12^{n-1}$$ for $n-1\ne1$

Comment: The common ratio is not $12$.

Answer (score 2):

$$4\cdot3^{n-1}=78732$$ or
$$3^{n-1}=19683$$ (here was your mistake) or
$$n=1+\frac{\ln19683}{\ln3},$$
which gives $n=10.$

Also, it's better to learn that $$3^9=19683.$$

Answer (score 1):

The general term of the progression is $a_n=4\cdot3^{n-1}$ with $n\geq1$. So, I have:
$$4\cdot3^{n-1}=78732$$Posing $\alpha=n-1$, I obtain $\alpha=9$ and so $n=10$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand I got it now

Answer (score 1):

**Without logarithms:**

This is the same as finding $n$ for $\dfrac{78732}4=19683$ in $\dfrac44,\dfrac{12}4,\dfrac{36}4,\cdots=3^0,3^1,3^2,\cdots$

To find the right power, for efficiency we square recursively,

$$3^2=9,3^4=81,3^8=6561$$ and notice that $19683=3\cdot6561=3^9$. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $78732 = 4\cdot3^{n-1}$ does not imply $78732 = 12^{n-1},$ as you wrote. Instead, from the first equation, divide both sides by $4$ to get $19683= 3^{n-1}.$ This says that $19683$ is some power of $3.$ Multiply both sides by $3$ to give $$3×19683 = 3^n.$$  Now taking logs to base $3$ gives $$1+\log{19683}=n,$$ which you may work out on a calculator.

Comment: Mh, the sum of digits of $78372$ is $27$...

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks. Now corrected. I made a numerical gaffe. Was working manually.

Comment: When working manually, check with the… proof by nine ;-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I know. Moreover, I was working with a different number -- $78372,$ instead of $78732.$ I sometimes unconsciously perform such permutations. Let's just say I'm not very good numerically. :)

Comment: Use CRC's in your computations then…

Comment: @YvesDaoust What's that?

Comment: Cyclic Redundancy Check, detects digit inversion ;-)